# Problem with React Router v6 - Showing a blank page

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-router

I'm trying to figure out how to use react-router for applications with react. But my route part doesn't work, it shows a blank page in any case.

Here are the code parts of the files used:

**index.js**

```
import ReactDOM from "react-dom"
import App from './components/App';
import 'bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css'

ReactDOM.render(
  <React.StrictMode>
    <App />
  </React.StrictMode>,
  document.getElementById('root')
);
```

**App.js**

```
import { Container } from "react-bootstrap";
import Signup from "./Signup";
import HomePage from "./HomePage";
import { AuthProvider } from "../context/AuthContext"
import { BrowserRouter as Router, Routes, Route } from 'react-router-dom'

function App() {
 return (
   <Container className="d-flex aling-items-center justify-content-center" style={{ minHeight: "100vh" }}>
   <div className="w-100" style={{ maxWidth: "400px", display: "flex", flexDirection: "column", justifyContent: "center"}}>
     <Router>
       <AuthProvider>
         <Routes>
           <Route path="/" element={<HomePage />}></Route>
           <Route path="/signup" element={<Signup />}></Route>
         </Routes>
       </AuthProvider>
     </Router>
  </div>
 </Container>
 )
}

export default App;
```

**Home.js** and **Signup.js**

```
import React from 'react'

export default function HomePage() {
  return (
    <div>This is the homepage</div>
  )
}
```

**AuthContext.js** and **firebase.js**

```
import React, { useContext, useState, useEffect } from 'react'
import { auth } from '../firebase'

const AuthContext = React.createContext()

export function useAuth() {
    return useContext(AuthContext)
}

export function AuthProvider({children}) {

    const [currentUser, setCurrentUser] = useState()
    const [loading, setLoading] = useState('true')

    function signup(email, password) {
        return auth.createUserWithEmailAndPassword(email, password)
    }

    useEffect(() => {
        const unsubscribe = auth.onAuthStateChanged(user => {
            setCurrentUser(user)
            setLoading('false')
        })
    
        return unsubscribe

    }, [])

    const value = {
        currentUser,
        signup
    }

  return (
      <AuthContext.Provider value={value}>
          {!loading && children}
      </AuthContext.Provider>
  )
}

//------------------(firebase.js)---------------------

import firebase from 'firebase/compat/app'
import "firebase/compat/auth"

const app = firebase.initializeApp({
    apiKey: "***************************************",
    authDomain: process.env.REACT_AUTH_DOMAIN,
    projectId: process.env.REACT_PROJECT_ID,
    storageBucket: process.env.REACT_STORAGE_BUCKET,
    messagingSenderId: process.env.REACT_MESSAGING_SENDER_ID,
    appId: process.env.REACT_APP_ID
})

export const auth = app.auth()
export default app
```

I had to specify the key as a string because writing it as the other parameters didn't work

I've also tried using different versions of react-router, reading other answered questions, or writing the code differently. Nothing worked

Comment: I don't see any overt issue with the specific code you've shared in a snippet. I've copy/pasted it into a running [codesandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/problem-with-react-router-v6-showing-a-blank-page-rrkz27) and it runs without issue. Do you see any errors in the browser's console? What debugging have you done?

Comment: The console contains the warnings shown in the attached image. I couldn't think of any way to debug (i'm very new to react), could you suggest me something? Thank you

https://imgur.com/a/vwUAjkc

Comment: Those are only warnings. I suppose first check that `App` is rendering as you expect. Comment out the router and routes and render something trivial like `<Container .......>Hello World!</Container>`. Then incrementally add back in your UI elements/components until it breaks, then repeat the process for *that* element/component until you narrow it down to the offending element/component. Try that codesandbox to see if you can create a demo that reproduces the issue that we could inspect and debug live.

Comment: I tried to create a sandbox and everything works fine. The only difference from the original code is the lack of the part relating to integration with firebase, so I removed authcontext from the file and it worked. I am thinking that the problem is in that file, I changed the question and added the code contained in authcontext.js and firebase.js

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don't use strings `"true"` and `"false"` in lieu of *actual* boolean values. Non-empty strings are ***always*** truthy. Change your `loading` state from strings to booleans.

```
export function AuthProvider({ children }) {
  const [currentUser, setCurrentUser] = useState();
  const [loading, setLoading] = useState(true);

  function signup(email, password) {
    return auth.createUserWithEmailAndPassword(email, password);
  }

  useEffect(() => {
    const unsubscribe = auth.onAuthStateChanged(user => {
       setCurrentUser(user);
       setLoading(false);
    });
    
    return unsubscribe;
  }, [])

  const value = {
    currentUser,
    signup
  };

  return (
    <AuthContext.Provider value={value}>
      {!loading && children}
    </AuthContext.Provider>
  );
}
```